# Lamp configuration on CentOS

Tags: apache, apache2

I have installed LAMP on my CentOS server VM, where I want to access my server by the browser of my local machine, but it doesn't work. Please help me find the solution.

Comment: You need to be much clearer. What did you do to install LAMP, how do access by browser and what results do you obtain?

Comment: i have installed lamp  on my centos server (vmware), whene i wanted to test my server lamp from my local machine windows , so the probleme is the my browser can't know the ip addresse of my centos server vm , is it clear ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's running? 
try

```
ps ax | grep httpd | grep -v grep
```

and if you see no output do:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

The server will be accessible on your configured virtual host. Make sure you follow each step in this [guide](http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/%28ve%29%3aInstall_LAMP_on_CentOS).

Comment: thanks for the answer, i have followed each step in the guide but don't work to me

Answer (score 0):

Is your VM network bridged or NAT'ted? If bridged, something on the VM is wrong as it should just show as a standard machine on your network. If NAT'ted, you will need to read up on NAT connections in your virtualisation documenation.

Comment: it's Nat'ted ,so what do you think is the probleme ?

Comment: i didn't understand what do you mean : you will need to read up on Nat connections in your virtualisation documentation?

Comment: As the VM is NAT'ted, it will appear to the outside world as having the IP address of the host machine. Therefore, you will most likely need to do some port forwarding on your host machine to allow your local machine to access it. How this is done depends on the virtualisation system you're using. For example, in VirtualBox, this page ([http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward]) shows how to port forward a port on your host machine to your virtual machine.

Comment: I use vmware, how i can do that ?

Comment: Check the documentation. Search it for "NAT" and "port forward". You have the documentation so it's easier for you to check it as I'm not going to go to the VMWare site, download their documentation and search it for you.